# How can you create a combination scope/trait declarator in Raku?

Tags: testing, metaprogramming, raku

Let's get straight to the point. I want to create a declarator, let's call it `testable`, that is the combination of `our` and `is export`, so that instead of writing

```
our $foo is export;
```

we would simply write

```
testable $foo;
```

I'm pretty sure something can be done through the [metamodel](https://docs.raku.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW), but I'm not sure this precise thing (scope and trait) can be done or, for that matter, how.

Comment: .oO [ "I wanted to say "Hi" on this dark and stormy night, and share how cool it is that a programming language, or more to the point its culture, helped folk learn to make good choices. Oh, also, that while a slang macro of `our $foo is export;` was a 1 liner in the 2020s, it takes *less than a single bit* in version Z, thanks to the new version of Damian's Quantum::Computation (for obvious reasons I can only share [a link to it as it was in 2020](https://gist.github.com/raiph/4c374da060159c92176273cc982a2d3c)." ~~ [The 13th Time Lord](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLun2Cct_u0#t=33s). ]

Comment: @raiph c'mon, release it in the ecosystem!